# Is there an almost strongly zero-dimensional space which is not strongly zero-dimensional

Tags: gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, dimension-theory

A Tychonoff space $X$ is called *strongly zero-dimensional* if each functionally closed subset $F$ of $X$ is a *$C$-set*, which means that $F$ is the intersection of a sequences of clopen sets in $X$.

A Tychonoff space $X$ is called *almost strongly zero-dimensional* if each functionally closed subset of $X$ is the union of a sequence of $C$-sets.

> **Question.** Does there exists a (metrizable separable) Tychonoff space which is almost strongly zero-dimensional but not strongly zero-dimensional?

This problem was posed on 30.11.2019 by [Olena Karlova](http://schoolsite.org.ua/4/) (from Chernivtsi) on [page 35](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=3&page=35) of [Volume 3](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=3) of [the Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/view.php).

**Prize.** A portrait of a mathematician who will solve this problem :)

Comment: The definition of strong zero-dimensionality in most books is stronger: disjoint functionally closed sets can be separated by clopen sets.

Comment: @KPHart You are right, but I just have preserved the terminology of the author of the problem. In fact, the question is non-trivial already at the level of metrizable separable spaces where the strong zero-dimensionality (in all senses) is equivalent to the standard zero-dimensionality.

Comment: The ``metrizable separable" case of this problem is equivalent to this MO-problem (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/240215/do-g-delta-measurable-maps-preserve-dimension), which has an affirmative answer if the space $X$ is analytic, i.e., a continuous image of a Polish space. Therefore, we have a partial answer for analytic spaces: each  almost strongly zero-dimensional analytic metrizable separable space is strongly zero-dimensional.

Comment: @KPHart "Your" definition and "my" definition of strongly zero-dimensional space are equivalent, because every two disjoint C-sets can be separated by clopen sets

Comment: The following Lemma should be useful (if it's true): Let $X$ be a separable metrizable space. If $F$ is a C-set in $X$, and $F=A\sqcup B$ with $A$ and $B$ disjoint closed $\sigma$C-sets, then there is an $X$-clopen set containing $A$ and missing $B$.

Comment: @TarasBanakh For the zero-dimensional space $Y$ I assume you want the set $X$ in the topology generated by all of the clopen sets.  But how do you know this topology is metrizable?

Comment: @D.S.Lipham Probably, you are right: the metrizability does not follow, but maybe the analyticity can be still applied?

Comment: @TarasBanakh Not sure if I'm making this too difficult... it just seems like the usual Jayne-Rogers results require our $Y$ to be metrizable.

Comment: @D.S.Lipham Then this is a good occasion to generalize (or at least to try) the Jayne-Rogers theorem.

Comment: @ Are there any good references for continuous images of Polish spaces, where the image is not necessarily metrizable? Are you sure the desired theorem holds when $X$ is Polish?

Comment: @D.S.Lipham A good reference is this book: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-0529-0

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but this may be helpful:

**Theorem 1.** If $X$ is a Lindelöf Tychonoff almost strongly zero-dimensional space, then the  following are equivalent:

(i) $X$ is strongly zero-dimensional;

(ii) $X$ is *almost zero-dimensional*, that is, $X$ has a neighborhood basis of C-sets.

Proof. (i)$\Rightarrow$(ii) is trivial, and the converse follows from Theorem 4.3 in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/334759449_A_note_on_cohesive_almost_zero-dimensional_space) (we assume separable metrizable there, but Lindelöf should be enough). $\square$

In light of Taras Banakh's comment above, for separable metrizable spaces I believe the question is: *If $X$ is separable metrizable and $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous bijection onto a zero-dimensional space $Y$ which maps open sets to $G_\delta$-sets, then is $X$ almost zero-dimensional?*

**Theorem 2.** Every almost strongly zero-dimensional homogeneous Polish space $X$ is (strongly) zero-dimensional.

Proof. If $U$ is any open subset of $X$, then $U$ is a $\sigma$C-set, so by the Baire property there is a C-set $F\subseteq U$ which contains a non-empty open set.  Continuing this process we construct C-sets $F_n$ such that $F_{n+1}\subseteq F^\mathrm{o}_n$ and $\text{diam}(F_n)\leq 1/n$ in a complete metric.  Then there exists $x\in \bigcap F_n$, and $x$ has a neighborhood basis of C-sets.  By homogeneity, $X$ is almost zero-dimensional, so by Theorem 1 $X$ is strongly zero-dimensional. $\square$

More generally it is true that each almost strongly zero-dimensional Polish space is zero-dimensional at a dense $G_\delta$-set of points.