# Separating a countable closed set from a point

Tags: gn.general-topology, dimension-theory

Let  be a separable metrizable space. An intersection of clopen subsets of $X$ is called a *C-set*.

**Question.** If each singleton of $X$ is a C-set,   $A\subseteq X$ is closed and countable,  $x\in X\setminus A,\,$ and $A\cup \{x\}$ is a C-set, then is there a clopen subset of $X$ containing $A$ and missing $x$?

This question may be connected to [Is there an almost strongly zero-dimensional space which is not strongly zero-dimensional](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347721/is-there-an-almost-strongly-zero-dimensional-space-which-is-not-strongly-zero-di/347768#347768) and [Do $G_\delta$-measurable maps preserve dimension?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/240215/do-g-delta-measurable-maps-preserve-dimension).

Comment: @WlodAA You are correct I wanted $x\in X\setminus A$ (thanks for edit). But the answer is not so clear to me...

Comment: I was mistaken. (I'll remove a couple of my comments that used to be above).